# Executar jQuery para selecionar Solicitante

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho o seguinte jQuery:

```
function clienteChange() {
    var id = $('#idCliente').val();
    $.ajax( 
    { 
        url:"/Administrar/clientes.endereco.php?id=" + id, 
        dataType : 'json', 
        success:function(result) { 
            $('[name^="cham_endereco[]"]').val(result.endereco); 
            $('[name^="cham_numero[]"]').val(result.numero); 
            $('[name^="cham_bairro[]"]').val(result.bairro); 
            $('[name^="cham_cidade[]"]').val(result.cidade); 
        } 
    }); 

    var selectSolicitante = jQuery(id).parents('tr').find('select.selectSolicitante');
    selectSolicitante.html('<option value="0">Carregando...</option>');
    $.post("/Administrar/clientes.solicitante.php?idCliente=" + id,
        {solicitante:jQuery(id).val()},
        function(valor){
            selectSolicitante.html(valor);
        }
    );
}
```

O primeiro bloco funciona corretamente, exibe certinho os dados no endereço, número... Queria que ao selecionar o cliente, executasse esse primeiro bloco mas também executasse o segundo bloco, buscando os solicitantes précadastrados... Fiz o teste, mas não funciona.

Segue o PHP também:

```
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');

    echo "<option>teste</option>";
```

A tela de cadastro é esta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual teste você fez?

Comment: Selecionei o cliente normal... E no console não retornou nada de erros também... Mas não exibe também as opções do campo. Coloquei um print do formulário para entender melhor.

Comment: Teria que retornar o teste...

Comment: Em que momento você executa a função `clienteChange()`?

Comment: <select class="input-xxlarge" style="width: 409px !important;" id="idCliente" name="idCliente" onchange="clienteChange()" >

Comment: Mas qual é esse `select` na sua tela?

Comment: Neste momento, eu executo ele... tipo, ele exibe certinho o endereço do cliente, quando seleciona, mas queria que ao selecionar o cliente, carregasse também o solicitante

Comment: Este select que eu te passei, é o "Cliente"

Comment: O código `$.post("/Administrar/clientes.solicitante.php?idCliente=" + id,` é executado? Outra dúvida, porque é um método `POST` e você passa a variável na `URL`?

Comment: Verdade, posso tirar o GET, mas ele executa a url sim.

Comment: Você consegue verificar utilizando `console.log(valor)` antes de `selectSolicitante.html(valor);`? Você já verificou se esta enviando o `id`?

Comment: <option>teste</option> Retornou este no console, mas, no campo não

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26743/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-gerep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifique se o seu comando `var selectSolicitante = jQuery(id).parents('tr').find('select.selectSolicitante');` esta realmente retornando o elemento que você procura.

Minha sugestão é, se possível, dar um `id` ou uma `class` ao seu elemento, deixando seu código assim:

```
    $(".selectSolicitante").html('<option value="0">Carregando...</option>');
    $.post("/Administrar/clientes.solicitante.php?idCliente=" + id,
        {solicitante:jQuery(id).val()},
        function(valor){
            $(".selectSolicitante").html(valor);
        }
    );
```

É importante deixar o `html(valor)` porque desse modo, quando o seu `post` retornar os valores que você precisa, ele vai remover o **Carregando** da sua `select`

Comment: Deu certo, fico grato pela ajuda!